# missing field `registration_key` in initializer of `database::models::RegistrationKeys`

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

Here is my struct definition

```
pub struct RegistrationKeys {
    pub id: i64,
    pub registration_key: String,
}
```

Here's my table definition

```
CREATE TABLE
    IF NOT EXISTS RegistrationKeys (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        registration_key TEXT,
        owned BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
        owned_by INTEGER
    );
```

I'm attempting to grab the `id` field by the `registration_key` field

```
let registration_key = String::from("ABCD"); // I've also tried using &str
let response = query_as!(
    RegistrationKeys,
    "SELECT id FROM RegistrationKeys WHERE registration_key = $1",
    registration_key
)
.fetch_one(&pool)
.await;
```

I feel like it's expecting me to somehow bind the query result to `registration_key` like String::from("RESULT") but I can't figure out how I would do this nor find any examples anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to partially intialize your `RegistrationKeys` struct, you should consider retrieving the `registration_key` as well from your query:

```sql
SELECT id, registration_key FROM RegistrationKeys WHERE registration_key = $1
```

Comment: That helped a lot! I also had to restructure my query as well as wrap my field names with quotes like below
`query_as::<_, RegistrationKeys>(r#"SELECT "id", "registration_key" FROM RegistrationKeys WHERE "registration_key" = $1;"#,).bind(registration_key)`